# SSRS css messing up?

Tags: sql-server, css, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

So the last couple of days my dev webpage for ssrs has been looking really weird, as if it's not getting styled by css at all.  I'm not the only person that is seeing it like this.  We just rebooted the server and it didn't have any effect.  If you know what it causing this, please help.

another symptom is that i can't modify security settings now.

[image: Prod]

[image: Dev]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would view the page using FF (firebug), and take a look in the head to see whether the CSS is being imported.

If it is, make sure the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of general things come to mind...

- Make sure your IIS application/virtual directory settings are correct especially if you are using SSRS2005. The default IIS applications are "Reports" and "ReportServer"
- Make sure the NTFS rights are correct for Local path. For example the default location for ReportServer is "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer"

In my experience when strange things like this are happening there are user rights/access issues. Especially when you can't modify security settings.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Well it kinda seems to have fixed itself.

Comment: The same thing will happen if when connecting to the webserver it doesn't send the css file to the browser, or if it is corrupted for some reason.  If you occasionally get 404's when browsing or have network hickups this is most likely the cause, and the reason why it will come and go randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit naive, but have you tried an offline version of the code?

Get the generated HTML via "view source" in your browser of choice, then get the stylesheet by accessing it directly from the same browser, using whatever the path is from the html (I recommend Google Chrome, as the view source provides clickable hyperlinks within the source). Put them both on your desktop, making sure the relative paths are preserved, and see what it looks like offline.

I'm sure that the server/Microsoft produce all of this code and so it's SUPPOSED to work, so a missing closing tag or misplaced semi-colon is probably not the answer, but I have found more than once that pulling my output off the server and onto my desktop has made the problem go from mysterious to "Oh! Duh! /styles/style.css, not /Styles/style.css" etc etc.

The problem can only be with your server if www doesn't have read/execute access to all of the right folders. I find this really unlikely, but it's easy to check by simply trying to view the source code of the CSS. If you can, the problem is post-server output.